# Python bug? equivalent functions - variable overflow in one but not in the other

Tags: python

I have the following two (supposedly equivalent) functions, to see which one executes faster (will be used to process a large data set)

```
import numpy as np


def interval_energy(array, start_intensity, intensity_window_length):
    bins = np.bincount(array.ravel())
    energy = 0
    for i in range(start_intensity, min(start_intensity + intensity_window_length, len(bins))):
        energy += bins[i] * (i ** 2)

    print("Energy: {}".format(energy))
    return energy


def interval_energy2(array, start_intensity, intensity_window_length):
    flat_array = array.ravel()
    energy = 0
    for i in range(0, array.size):
        if start_intensity <= flat_array[i] < (start_intensity + intensity_window_length):
            energy += flat_array[i] ** 2

    print("Energy2: {}".format(energy))
    return energy
```

i'm using the following code to test the code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    setup = """
from interval_energy import interval_energy, interval_energy2
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(0, 3000, (150, 150, 150))
    """

    t = timeit.Timer('interval_energy(a, 50, 2450)', setup)
    t2 = timeit.Timer('interval_energy2(a, 50, 2450)', setup)
    t3 = timeit.Timer("""
interval_energy(a, 50, 2450)
interval_energy2(a, 50, 2450)
    """, setup)

    print(t.timeit(5))
    print(t2.timeit(5))
    print(t3.timeit(5))
```

in interval_energy2 however, the energy variable overflows with this error being raised:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars
```

Update 1: I have noticed that in the first version, energy is of type int when its created and int64 when its returned, whereas in the second version of the function it is also of type int when its created however stays int32 until the point where it is returned. thus the overflow. Why does Python automatically convert the variable in one case but not in the other

Update 2: its been established that the two functions in theory produce the same result.

<strike>Update 3: I'm using Python3.5.2 64bit. I have read that Python3 ONLY uses long, so what I see here (32bit integer overflow) should not even be possible?</strike> possible because of c-stack of pandas /numpy

**Update 4: Possible bug with CPython for windows, as the identical code works fine on OSX / unix (same python, numpy versions used on both systems)**

Comment: have you tried with smaller ranges?

Comment: well in the end this is the amount of data it will have to deal with, so whats the point?

Comment: the point is to see if results are really equivalent.

Comment: So, you have proved they're not equivalent - what is the question?

Comment: @TomDalton well. if you are going to formulate it that way the question is, why are the two functions not equivalent? they SHOULD perform the same.

Comment: @muragtu, when using dtype='int64' as f5r5e5d suggested in his answer, you can verify that the result is equivalent.

Comment: I added count = 0 before each loop, increased it inside (within if in energy2), and got 2450 iterations for energy1, and 2756291 for energy 2. Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: @kabanus it is certainly possible yes, because the second version iterates over each element of the array (150x150x150 = 3375000) whereas the first one only iterates over each possible value occuring the  array (0-3000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. This is a good question:

```
print type(flat_array[3])
<type 'numpy.int32'>
```

**but**, after the bincount:

```
print type(bins[3])
<type 'numpy.int64'>
```

apparently the binning converted the data type, without you noticing! This is why the fix by f5r5e5d  worked. So you should have got an error on both, but the first got spared. Change your array definition:

```
a = np.random.randint(0, 3000, (150, 150, 150),dtype=np.int64)
```

as f5r5e5d suggested. I get no error and close, but not identical results - that's up to you.

**EDIT**
Currently it seems like on versions after 2.7.9, where dtype is an allowed keyword of array, the default dtype is according to the values given to the array. Using `energy=np.int64()` will make sure the variable we expect to overflow is a large int.

Comment: good point @kabanus! however as I've said in Update 4 in the OP the "wrong" code works fine on non windows systems, how can that be?

Comment: My guess is defaults on 64/32 bit system/different python versions/configurations etc. This is reproducible on win 8 64bit. I'll try Debian and edit the answer.

Comment: also, yk noticed that int32 would be the correct choice for  the original array because the original array does not have any members that exceed the int32 maxsize limit.

Comment: 1) OK, I have py 2.7.9 on my debian. There the dtype keyword is not even allowed. @) On win 8 I have 2.7.12, the keyword is allowed. My guess is version issue. Can you confirm you're python is newer than 2.7.9? - To sum - guessing on newer versions it auto-selects dtype default according to max value.) So, if you want to be OK, and leave it int32, start energy as 'energy=np.int64', properly, since it needs to be.

Comment: using python 3.5.2

Comment: Yea so probably that's the issue. On Linux system the python distribution is often a bit behind.

Comment: so ultimately the answer is that in the first function energy is automatically selected to be int64, because bincount makes the array int64 and in the other it isn't`?

Comment: Yup, as I've written. You can check this with the code I posted.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you wanted flat_array in energy2 for loop range?

I changed the interval test to use "and"

and changed data type to  dtype='int64' in my cut down of your init:

```
import numpy as np


def interval_energy(array, start_intensity, intensity_window_length):
    bins = np.bincount(array.ravel())
    energy = 0
    for i in range(start_intensity, min(start_intensity + intensity_window_length, len(bins))):
    energy += bins[i] * (i ** 2)

    print("Energy: {}".format(energy))
    return energy


def interval_energy2(array, start_intensity, intensity_window_length):
    flat_array = array.ravel()
    energy = 0
    for i in range(0, flat_array.size):
        if start_intensity <= flat_array[i] and flat_array[i]  < (start_intensity + intensity_window_length):
        energy += flat_array[i] ** 2

    print("Energy2: {}".format(energy))
    return energy


import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(0, 3000, (150, 150, 150), dtype='int64')

interval_energy(a, 50, 2450)
interval_energy2(a, 50, 2450)
```

in Spyder I get:

```
In [53]:
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(0, 3000, (150, 150, 150), dtype='int64')

interval_energy(a, 50, 2450)
interval_energy2(a, 50, 2450)
Energy: 5859327673866
Energy2: 5859327673866
Out[53]: 5859327673866
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. changing range(0, array.size) to range(0, flat_array.size) makes no difference as both contain the same number of elements. also changing to "and" makes no difference, in fact pycharm recommends to simply the "and" statement to the way it was. using dtype='int64' works, but I do not understand why? shouldn't energy be internally set to the same datatype in both functions?

Comment: I'm a relative novice a Python and have no idea why one worked and the other didn't,  just keyed on the "RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars"  and that you result was bigger than 2^32